# need help in bash script for if and greater than

Tags: bash

i have

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
`elif [[$# -gt 31]]
```

when i execute following script (its part from script by "Fred Weinhaus" for text-cleaner) by python 3

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]     then    # help information
    echo ""
    usage2
    exit 0 elif [ $# -gt 31 ]               then    errMsg "--- TOO MANY ARGUMENTS WERE PROVIDED ---" else  while [ $# -gt 0 ]      do          # get parameter values          case "$1" in
          -h|-help)    # help information
                       echo ""
                       usage2
                       exit 0
                       ;;
```

how i solve this problem?

Comment: ";" after "]" is required.

Comment: i have tryed "elif [ $# -gt 31 ]; " but not working @YujiKonishi

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: See documentation: `help if`

Answer (score 0):

Your script has many mistakes. My fix may not be correct.
Define "usage2".

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then    # help information
    echo ""
    #usage2
    exit 0
elif [ $# -gt 31 ]; then
    errMsg "--- TOO MANY ARGUMENTS WERE PROVIDED ---"
else while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do # get parameter values
    case "$1" in
    -h|-help) # help information
        echo ""
        #usage2
        exit 0
        ;;                                                                                                         
    esac
    done
fi
```

There are no errors in lines no 201 and 206.
Try this code.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage2(){
    # dummy
    :
}

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo ""
    usage2
    exit 0
elif [[ $# -gt 31 ]]
then
    errMsg "--- TOO MANY ARGUMENTS WERE PROVIDED ---"
else
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
    do  
        :
    done                                  
fi
```

Comment: its part of code @Yuj Konishi , but also not working

Comment: Could you show all the codes?

Comment: https://github.com/youssriaboelseod/table-parser-opencv/blob/master/textcleaner

Comment: Too long. what line?

Comment: lines no 201 and 206

Comment: i have modify your code in scripts , get me the same error

Comment: not working ( i replace your code by this script ) : syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''

Comment: i am executing this code by Ubuntu on windows 10